# How to record input and output simulataneously from computer audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, podcast

I have Audacity, Pavucontrol, and Audio Recorder installed.

I'm currently on a Zoom meeting, and trying to test the record function.

Audio Recorder has the following options:

Built-in Audio Analogue (Audio Output)
Built-in Audio Analogue (Microphone)
Microphone Brand (Analogue Stereo (audio output)
Microphone Brand Mono (Microphone)
Systems' Default Device
User Defined Audio Source

I am trying to record the meeting with my microphone in, as this has the best quality. When I click on Microphone output, I get the sound from other people but not myself, and vice versa when I click on Microphone (Microphone).

When I open Pavucontrol there is a stream on the Recording tab that says "Zoom VoiceEngine" recStream from, but I have no idea to what to do with this. When I am recording using Audio Recorder, another stream appears, but it's still only one part.

So in general, I'm asking how can I record a session on zoom that includes ALL audio, including mine and the people on the other side?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[Blue Recorder](https://snapcraft.io/blue-recorder) worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 (Xorg). To install it run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo snap install blue-recorder
sudo snap connect blue-recorder:audio-record
sudo snap connect blue-recorder:screencast-legacy
```

The one caveat for meetings is that input audio should be disabled not in a meeting app but system-wide when you're not speaking.

Also, the current version of the app doesn't update "Record" button when recording audio-only. But it does record in the background. Stopping the recording is clicking "Record" button one more time.